# Cannot find the 'lg' (looking glass) command in Gnome3

Tags: gnome, looking-glass

I am not able to find the `lg` command in my Ubuntu 11.10 installation. I have installed Gnome3 from gnome.org website, following the install link for Ubuntu. So I think everything should be fine.

But the `lg` command is missing and I am not able to find any package providing it. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell development-tools true
```

And check again to see if 'lg' works.

Comment: I had this problem and flipping the setting to true worked. I wonder what process might have set it away from the default value of true.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, the command ["looking glass"](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/LookingGlass) is a part of the GNOME-Shell itself.
Make sure you have "gnome compatibility" activated in the Compiz config settings manager, and you have GNOME-Shell installed.

The "running command" shortcut normally is <kbd>Alt + F2</kbd>.

So, please press <kbd>Alt + F2</kbd>, a very simple command window will appear. Here you can type "lg" to activate this bug-tracking- and processes-information-window.

Comment: was to me (read the wiki too quickly) thx

Answer (score 0):

ALT + F2 doesn't work by default in GNOME Shell under Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot. To fix it, open "System Settings" and under Keyboard > Shortcuts > System, click "Disabled" next to "Show the run command prompt" and press ALT + F2 - this should set ALT + F2 for running the command prompt.

and to give credit where credit is due....

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html#more